# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: is not mapped [from Team]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm working on little Spring MVC CRUD application. Got some strange problems:

- configuration class:

  ```
  package sbk.spring.simplejc.config;

  import java.util.Properties;

  import javax.annotation.Resource;
  import javax.sql.DataSource;

  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
  import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
  import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
  import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
  import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

  @Configuration //Specifies the class as configuration
  @ComponentScan("sbk.spring.simplejc") //Specifies which package to scan
  //@Import({DataBaseConfig.class})
  @EnableTransactionManagement
  @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
  @EnableWebMvc //Enables to use Spring's annotations in the code
  public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
      private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER                   = "db.driver";
      private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD                 = "db.password";
      private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL                      = "db.url";
      private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME                 = "db.username";

      private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT                 = "hibernate.dialect";
      private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL                = "hibernate.show_sql";
      private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN    = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
      @Resource
      private Environment env;

      @Bean
      public DataSource dataSource() {
              DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
              dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
              dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
              dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
              dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
              return dataSource;
      }
      @Bean
      public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
          LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
          sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());     
          sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
          sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties()); 
          return sessionFactoryBean;
      }   
      private Properties hibProperties() {
              Properties properties = new Properties();
              properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
              properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
              return properties;        
      }
      @Bean
      public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
          HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
          transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
          return transactionManager;
      }
      @Override
      public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
              registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
      }
      @Bean
      public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {       
          UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
          resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
          resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
          resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
          return resolver;
      }
  }
  ```
- `application.properties`:

  ```
  #DB properties:  
  db.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
  db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=Examples 
  db.username=sa
  db.password=

  #Hibernate Configuration:  
  hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
  hibernate.show_sql=true  
  entitymanager.packages.to.scan=sbk.spring.simplejc.entity
  ```
- `@Entity` class:

  ```
  package sbk.spring.simplejc.entity;


      import javax.persistence.Entity;
      import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
      import javax.persistence.Id;
      import javax.persistence.Table;

      @Entity
      @Table(name="Team")
      public class Team {
          @Id
          @GeneratedValue
          private Integer id;
          private String name;
          private Integer rating;
          public Integer getId() {
              return id;
          }
          public void setId(Integer id) {
              this.id = id;
          }
          public String getName() {
              return name;
          }
          public void setName(String name) {
              this.name = name;
          }
          public Integer getRating() {
              return rating;
          }
          public void setRating(Integer rating) {
              this.rating = rating;
          }
      }
  ```
- Controller class:

  ```
  package sbk.spring.simplejc.controller;

  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
  import sbk.spring.simplejc.service.ITeamService;


  @Controller
  public class TeamController {
      @Autowired
      ITeamService service;

      @RequestMapping(value="/")
      public ModelAndView goToHelloPage() {
          ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
          view.addObject("teamList", service.listTeams());
          return view;
      }

  }
  ```
- Error stack trace:

  ```
      org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Team is not mapped [from Team]
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3420)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3309)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
          org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
          org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
          org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
          org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
          org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
          org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
          org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1777)
          sbk.spring.simplejc.dao.HibTeamDAO.listTeams(HibTeamDAO.java:23)
          sbk.spring.simplejc.service.TeamService.listTeams(TeamService.java:27)
  ```

I haven't got a clue about this issue.

---

### Update

- DAO class:

  ```
  package sbk.spring.simplejc.dao;

      import java.util.List;

      import org.hibernate.Session;
      import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
      import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
      import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
      import sbk.spring.simplejc.entity.Team;

      @Repository
      public class HibTeamDAO implements TeamDAO {    
          @Autowired
          private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
          public void addTeam(Team team) {
              sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(team);
          }
          public void updateTeam(Team team) {     
              sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(team);
          }
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          public List<Team> listTeams() {
              return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Team").list();
          }
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          public Team getTeamById(Integer teamID) {
              Session     session         =       sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();     
              List<Team>  listTeam        =       session.createQuery("from Team t where t.id = :teamID")
                                                  .setParameter("teamID", teamID)
                                                  .list();
              return listTeam.size()  > 0 ? (Team)listTeam.get(0) : null;
          } 
          public void removeTeam(Integer teamID) {
              Team team = (Team) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Team.class, teamID);
              if(team != null){
                  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(team);
              }
          }
          @Override
          public Integer count() {
              return (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select count(t) from Team t").uniqueResult();
          }
      }
  ```
- `TeamController` class:

  ```
  package sbk.spring.simplejc.controller;

  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
  import sbk.spring.simplejc.service.ITeamService;


  @Controller
  public class TeamController {
      @Autowired
      ITeamService service;

      @RequestMapping(value="/")
      public ModelAndView goToHelloPage() {
          ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
          view.addObject("teamList", service.listTeams());
          return view;
      }

  }
  ```

---

### Update

Now I got rid from this problem by changing DAO method from

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Team").list();
```

to

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from sbk.spring.simplejc.entity.Team").list();
```

But received another issue: every query return null despite of existing rows in `Team` table.

---

### Update

Finally I noticed warning messages:

```
Feb 15, 2014 7:01:05 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter concreteQueries
WARN: HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from sbk.spring.simplejc.entity.Team
```

---

### Update

At least I've sorted out this issue by adding next row of code in `dataSource` bean definition in `WebAppConfig`:

```
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());     
    sessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class[]{Team.class});//new row!!!
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties()); 
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to query `"Select * from Team"`

Comment: No, in this instance I've got  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from Team]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No, in this instance I've got org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from Team] –  Sobik Feb 15 at 10:29"

Instead "Select * from Team" try write "from Team". Because Hibernate works with java entity.

Comment: Dtry to improve formattingcand response by giving wome details

Comment: I've sorted this problem out, check last updates in main post

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was because I didn't have the hibernate packagesToScan property. I see that you have it. May be this comment will be useful for someone who missed it.

Comment: in my case this was exactly the issue.